# Mono repo, include *.d.ts on imports

Tags: typescript, monorepo, tsc

Situation:

Our monorepo has 2 workspaces: `foo` and `bar`.

`foo` has the files:

- `src/file.ts`
- `src/@types/baz.d.ts`

`bar` workspace imports `@monorepo/foo/src/file`.

Type-checks work for the `foo` workspace but not for the `bar` workspace.

How can I ask typescript to include the appropriate *.d.ts when importing from `@monorepo/foo/*`?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

**foo/tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "composite": true
  }
}
```

**bar/tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../foo",
      "declarationMap": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Use `tsc -b` instead of `tsc --noEmit`

`outDir` is not required but it will group all the built files in the same folder.